# Solution for Response code 302 in JMeter?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

Testing a web application.
I took 100 users, 100 ramp up & loop count 1 only for one web page.

Description of image 1 :
On HTTP Request page If i mark checked Follow Redirect then result is showing failed.

[image]

Description of image 2 :
On HTTP Request page,i didn't mark Follow Redirect checked & After creating the user i ran the test result is okay but response code :302 , response message :found

[image]

Is this an error? 
Then what is the solution for this?
Who will solve this, developer(who build the code) or tester(who is using jmeter)? ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNFjF.png)

Please some one reply.
Thanks

Comment: It seems that you get infinite redirect loop, most likely because site tries to set up cookie (Set-Cookie header in response in second screenshot). Try to add Cookie Manager element to your test plan.

Comment: Its good to use stack overflow to get answers but I suggest you should read about using JMeter and some sample tutorial. Many of the questions you asked are RTM or STW type or domain related questions. Before posting question please use all possible resources like manual/web and check duplicate/similar is already present or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an Error, the application has been designed to behave in this manner.

HTTP Code: 302 - is a common way to do URL redirection.

Hope this will help.

Comment: okay, i understood the meaning of Response Code 302 but what about java.io.IOException ? What is the solution for it ?

Comment: Increase the value of below property in jmeter.properties in bin folder.
"httpsampler.max_redirects=10"

The reason for the second scenario to be success is because it stops after receiving the first response i.e. "redirection call" and does not complete the actual flow defined by the developer.

Comment: if the problem still persists, you need to consult the developer & Infra team about redirection calls.  

I would also suggest to keep "Implementation" as "Java" in your HTTP sampler. There is a Known bug regarding this "Implementation" issue.

Comment: Thanks! @Jmeter PerfTest -  Please, Tell me one more thing,In bin folder, i am able to see file name which is create by me. Can you explain How can i increase the value?

Comment: In Jmeter Bin folder, search for file "Jmeter.properties". You should not create the file.

Comment: In "jmeter.properties" file, search for "httpsampler.max_redirects" property and set the property value as "10". Save the file & restart jmeter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Its helping me...I increased the value "httpsampler.max_redirects=10" but still i am facing the same problem. Now i have to talk with developers of my team. @Jmeter PerfTest

Comment: can you tell me about these two errors also  :                           1.Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException                                                                           2.Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException                                                                                                                                             Why it comes ? how can i solve it? It is occurring cause of testing process? or resolving it is a developers job?

Comment: How many users/threads are you using?   Also did you change "Implementation" in HTTP sampler to "Java"??

Comment: I am using for 1000 users & now i am changing it & will check the changes.

Comment: i changed "HTTP sampler" to "JAVA sampler " . results are okay but Response Code, Response Message & Response Data is coming blank.There is no failure but why these parts are blank? please reply asap .

Comment: Do not change the sampler, you need to use "HTTP Sampler".

I guess you got me wrong.  In "HTTP Sampler" look for "Implementation" setting/property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62798/discussion-between-jmeter-perftest-and-sonam-bharti).

Comment: Oh! yes i misunderstood. I am very new in JMeter that's why i was getting wrong. Now i changed "Implementation" as "JAVA" in HTTP Request sampler but one new error is showing : Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException Response message: Non HTTP response message: abc.co/landing.php